# Go to next for of loop iteration only when

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `for of` loop:

```
for (const element of $array) {
    let my_value = await GM.getValue("my_value");
}
```

Works fine.

Now, I **only** want to go to the next loop iteration when `my_value` is *not* empty. If it is empty, I want it to wait for `my_value` to have content before moving on to the next iteration.

So far, I've tried a `do..while` approach:

```
for (const element of $array) {
  do {
    let my_value = await GM.getValue("my_value");

    if (my_value) continue;
  } while (0);
}
```

But it's not working.

What's the correct approach to do this?

Comment: just you can use ```break``` statement
Example: 
for (const element of array) {
    if(element === 2) break;
    console.log(element)
}

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad How do you mean? My aim is to loop through *all* the array elements. I just want to continue the loop only when `my_value` is _not_ empty. So basically, "wait" for `my_value` to have content.

Comment: what happens when `my_value` is _never_ not empty. Do you intend on having some infinite loop protection?

Comment: I think you can use Esema 2018:

for await (variable of iterable) {
  statement
}

Comment: Another point to note, `GM.getValue` is async, so surely internally it should only be returning a value when it has something to return. You shouldn't have to continually poll an async function waiting for it to have something to tell you. I thinmk you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - perhaps try including what `GM.getValue` is doing!

Comment: @Jamiec I can simply setup a timeout if needed to clear the "infinite loop". Something I can figure out myself. The main aim with this question is to understand how I can "wait" for `my_value` to have content before I move on to the next iteration.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson that's what await does, assuming you're using it on a promise.

Comment: @KevinB Please post an answer demonstrating this.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Please see the async/await docs or any of the hundreds of questions about this.

Comment: We need more information. What is GM.getValue? what does it do, how does it do it. If it's like any other promise, it won't resolve until it has a value. If it's a synchronous method that returns immediately, `await` is useless for this purpose and you'd effectively need to check it every n seconds... horribly inefficient, but doable with a little bit more code. (i will not provide an example of the latter, as it's a rather poor practice.) The better alternative would be to fix GM.getValue in the latter.

Comment: ```const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

const forLoop = async () => {
  let loop = true;
  for (const variable of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) { 
     await sleep(1000);
       console.log(variable * 2, "DoWhile");
       
       if(variable * 2 === 6){
        break;
       }
     
     console.log(variable, "above")
  }
}

forLoop()```

Comment: I think this what you want, base on your code no need for do while and nested loop, you can handling it via control async and await only...I set a condition for break loop and make a wait behaver ==== https://jsfiddle.net/75o3xh2a/

Answer (score -1):

The short answer here is that there should be nothing more to do, as `GM.getValue` should only be resolving it's promise when it has a value to return. You shouldn't need to poll that method to "wait" for it to have a response.

Let me illustrate this with a mockup. In this example, my `getValue` method resolves after a short delay. This simulates it doing some work (perhaps loading some data from a database, or receiving something from a 3rd party system - it doesn't matter). My loop only continues after that action has taken place

```js
const GM = {
   getValue: function(input) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,2000, input))
   }
}


const $array = [1,2,3,4,5];

(async () => {
  for (const element of $array) {
      let my_value = await GM.getValue("my_value");
      console.log(element, my_value);
  }
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

Base on discuses on comments above, We can say base on your code no need for do while and nested loop, you can handling it via control `async/await` only...I set a condition for break loop and make a wait behave...

What its do when loop is start via `async/awais` the loop will wait the promise and you can what you need to do...

```
const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

const forLoop = async () => {
  let loop = true;
  for (const variable of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) { 
     await sleep(1000);// Wait
       console.log(variable * 2, "DoWhile");// Then do somthing
           
// Break when you need and base any condition...
       if(variable * 2 === 6){
        break;
       }
     
     console.log(variable, "above")
  }
}

forLoop()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75o3xh2a/